# Kyrgyzstan - Re-entry under visa exemption

Tags: visas, borders, kyrgyzstan

Holders of passports issued by EU nations are not required to obtain a visa for Kyrgyzstan up to the length of 60 days.

My question is, are there any restrictions (Time limit) to re-enter the country. In my case I want to go to Uzbekistan and then again come back to Kyrgyzstan by road.  I haven't found any helpful information so far even on ministry of external affairs and on Embassy websites.

Comment: Theres no time limit, but you have to prove you're not trying to live there to the IO, alternatively you can get an e-visa that lasts 90 days and it can be extended there too. http://www.evisa.e-gov.kg/